# adding JSON in javascript with multiple urls

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, mapbox

I need to parse through several JSON files, extract different values and then compare these values. I'm having trouble getting more than one JSON file to show up though...I think the"request.onload" only works once in the for-loop so maybe thats the reason.

```
var myArray = [7138, 6237];
for (i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
  //var id = 55;
  var head = "https://developer.trimet.org/ws/V2/arrivals/locIDs/";
  var tail = "/appID/30BE7218095886D573C04A41C/xml='true'";
  var url = head + myArray[i] + tail;
  //console.log(url);

  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('GET', url);
  request.responseType = 'json';
  request.send();

  request.onload = function() {
    var arrivalData = request.response;

    console.log(arrivalData.resultSet);

}}
```

Explaination of the code: the array "myArray" contains two bus-stop IDs which are found with another piece of code (I am making small app to find the 10 closest bus stops and then tell the user how long before the next bus arrives at each bus stop. To test it out, I am just using two constant IDs). These IDs are plugged into a url that contains a JSON script detailing the bus schedule for that bus stop.

I want to extract the JSON and save it as a separate JSON within the code. I think the current code does this now, but it only seems to work once. In the end, the for loop will add the arrival times to an array, these times will be compared to see which one comes sooner, then the soonest arrival time and its corresponding bus-stop ID will be found. Finally i want to make this a function that can take any array of bus-stop IDs so that I can find the soonest bus arrival time for any set of bus stops.

If you want to look into the arrival times, you can go to the url link and see the JSON - the arrival times can be either "estimated" or "scheduled" and the values are in milliseconds since Jan 1 1970.

If someone could help me just be able to access the JSONs outside of the request.onload function, i'd be very grateful.

Comment: You are creating a new XMLHttpRequest object for every loop of the array so the onload event will be separate for each one. Try defining the onload function before request.open().

Comment: From [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest):

Note: You need to add the event listeners before calling open() on the request.  Otherwise the progress events will not fire.

Comment: moving the request.send() after the function seemed to work. how would I add certain attributes of each JSON to an array?

Comment: If you know which properties your object will have you can just define an array in the global scope then use the array.push(object.property) method.

Comment: Added as an answer to give an example

Answer (score 1):

XMLHttpRequest works in asynchronous manner. And for loop is synchronous. So your facing this problem. I think below piece of code solves your problem

```
var myArray = [7138, 6237];
  myArray.forEach(function (id)  {
    //var id = 55;
    var head = "https://developer.trimet.org/ws/V2/arrivals/locIDs/";
    var tail = "/appID/30BE7218095886D573C04A41C/xml='true'";
    var url = head + id + tail;
    //console.log(url);

    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', url);
    request.responseType = 'json';
    request.send();

    request.onload = function() {
      var arrivalData = request.response;

      console.log(arrivalData.resultSet);

    }
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding as an answer too

```
var myArray = [7138, 6237];
//Define results globally
var results = [];

for (i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
  //var id = 55;
  var head = "https://developer.trimet.org/ws/V2/arrivals/locIDs/";
  var tail = "/appID/30BE7218095886D573C04A41C/xml='true'";
  var url = head + myArray[i] + tail;
  //console.log(url);

  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

  //Move here so onload event is registered
  request.onload = function() {
    var arrivalData = request.response;

    results.push(arrivalData.resultSet);

  };

  request.open('GET', url);
  request.responseType = 'json';
  request.send();

}
```

While this should work I think your problem could be solved with promises and it would make your code much more understandable.

Have a read on the [promise api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and especially Promise.All().

**EDIT**

Just a note on that requests array, since XMLHttpRequest and onload is asynchronous if you try to access the results array directly after running that for loop it will be empty. This is one of the reasons promises are so powerful.

Using the current method you won't have any way of knowing when both of the requests have finished unless you are constantly checking the length of the results array in a while loop or something, which would block the thread and make everything much worse.